# Expressionengine Module return array

Tags: php, expressionengine

So Im returning an array of all the information I need from my function, but I can seem to figure out how to parse through the array once I get to the templete.

Module:

```
Class main{
 function data(){
      blah blah blah 
      return $array;
 }
}
```

Template:

```
{exp:main:data}{data}{/exp:main:data}
```

{data} returns “Array”

How can I parse through this in EE code or is there another to parse this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your array of data to the `parse_variables()` method of the `TMPL` (template) class.

`return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $data);`

Note also that if you're only returning a single row of data, that will need to live as its own array inside `$data`. This can be done quickly by passing your array as `array($data)`.

I'd suggest reading the [module development documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#parsing-variables) as well.

Lastly, you might want to post future EE-related questions over on the new [ExpressionEngine StackExchange](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It should be noted that Im on EE 1.6.x

Comment: Ah, indeed, that should be noted. In that case, I suggest you download the EE1 docs (not online anymore) from http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/ (upper-right link) and have a look at the development documentation therein. Been so long, I forget exactly how to parse EE1 variables. But they do explain it in the docs.